# Android : destroy activity before intent to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activity in my android application : 
1. LoginActivity : User can Login **as member by using password and email** or **as guest**
2. MainActivity : Showing user current location on map

Scenario :
1. User login as guest
2. Go to Main Activity **as guest**. (No NPE here)
3. User took some action that needed to login
4. Intent to LoginActivity
5. I need to destroy MainActivity before directing user to LoginActivity
6. User input username and password on LoginActivity
7. If user exist and password true go to MainActivity
8. NPE (or Null Pointer Exception) happened here.

So, in my case, i needed to destroy MainActivity (Point number 5) before directing user to LoginActivity. I've tried this :

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

final String message = getResources().getString(R.string.NCI);

builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("To do your action, we need you to logged in our server"))
.setTitle("LOGIN REQUIRED")
.setPositiveButton("OK",
    new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id){                         
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);

            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
);

builder.create().show();
```

## Log Cat

```
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh/com.yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at com.yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:817)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
07-25 16:04:27.287: E/AndroidRuntime(19823):    ... 11 more
```

I've tried onDestroy() by replacing finish() call method, but NPE (Null Pointer Exception) still happened. As the first time intent to MainActivity, NPE not happended.

What i want `is start MainActivity as the first time`. How i could do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please post your stack trace or log. We need to see where the NPE is occurring.

Comment: Since you are getting back after logging in, why don't you use startActivityForResult instead?

Comment: @Shlublu Oops, sorry i forget to post LogCat. NPE occuring on `propertyDownloader = new PropertyDownloader(this, myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), true, progressBar, listDataProperty, noProperty, context);` myLocation variable is null but at the first time, myLocation not null

Comment: So the NPE doesn't seem related to the posted code. Using finish() is ok, it is actually the good way forward to stop an Activity. Would you post the involved code?

Comment: Maybe post some more code around line 817 in your MainActivity. From your previous comment it seems to be generated by a variable you do not initialize, so it really has nothing to do with the activity life-cycle.

Comment: your error in main activity so please post whole code of main activity here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you need to call `finish()` to finish some activity inside the `anonymous inner class` like you did in above code,just pass the complete activity's name(the one which you want to destroy) ,like `MainActivity.this.finish()`..(where MainActivity is the one which you want to destroy)

Comment: Thanks for your response, give me a minute, and let me try.

Comment: @nobalG That's not really the problem, is it?

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly for me +1!

Answer (score 8):

i think there are little conceptual problem Actually  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag is Use is check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP so in that case there are no need finish() method it is already Remove mainActivity class but according to document you have to add one more Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to your intent.

So Replace

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

with

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

thats it...

Answer (score -1):

Create a static Activity object which activity finish on other activity and assign activity in this
i.e you can can add more activities

```
public class demoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Activity self_intent;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.demo_activity);
            selfintent=this;
    } 

   //Other functions--------------
}
```

do same for other activities

on other

```
activityCloseBtn= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_close_btn);
activityCloseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          demoActivity.selfintent.finish(); //for finish demoActivityactivity

          //for other activities Activity.selfintent.finish();
          finish();  //for finish current activity
      }
});
```